# How to create a repository workspace which contains all of the components of a stream using scm tool?

Tags: rtc, jazz, ibm-jazz

I'm attempting to automate the updating of a file in a stream using 'scm'

Here is how I think it should work :

1. Login to the repository as current user (me)
2. Create a new repository workspace which contains all of the components of a given Stream
3. Load the components of the newly created workspace
4. Update the file

I'm on point 2. Reading about the 'create workspace' doc on http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rtc/v1r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_scm_cli.html it does'nt mention how to create a new workspace which contains all of the components of a given stream.
So how can I implement point 2 ?

Any comments on my methodolgy if can be improved upon also appreciated.

I've logged into the rtc repo via scm and this is the command I am using to try and create
the snapshot from the stream

> scm create snapshot -n test -d test "mystream"

But I receive an error :

```
Problem running 'create snapshot':
subcommand "snapshot" requires argument-based initialization, but does not provide a directory argument.
```

Is my command correct ?

Comment: I just edited my answer with more detailed scm commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option would be to create first a **snapshot** on the stream, and then to add that snapshot to your repository workspace.

See [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/11627/possible-for-command-line-scm-tool-to-create-a-snapshot):

```
scm create snapshot [options] <workspace/stream>
```

That would add *all* the component baselines in one command, by associating the snapshot to the new stream (see [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/42310/question-related-to-delivering-snapshot-to-a-stream))

```
scm snapshot promote
```

Comment: there does not seem to be an option to create a snapshot on a stream ? Looking at output from  "scm help create snapshot" it seems I can just create a snapshot in a repository but I havent created a repositroy yet.

Comment: @user470184 no, you can use the name of a stream, not just the name of a repo workspace;

Comment: @user470184 I think you need to specify the id of the stream, not its name. If it doesn't recognize the id, it will default to requesting a repo workspace (hence the error message)

Comment: where can I access the ID of a stream ?

Comment: @user470184 good question. I am no longer at work, but I believe you can see it when listing the streams in the web interface.

Comment: when I search for the stream all I see is the name,owner,comment . Clicking into the stream just displays the stream component & name. Can you see its ID ?

Comment: @user470184 yes I can: look at the url, it ends with `&id=...`: here is your stream id.

Comment: thanks, I can now create a snapshot from the stream. So now I just need to create a new repository workspace, and add this new snapshot to this workspace and load the workspace ?

Comment: @user470184 yes, that is the idea.